# Unable to integrate Azure ML API with PHP

Tags: php, azure, curl, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I tried integrating Azure ML API with PHP but unfortunately getting an error in response.

Updated: I have used request response API sending through json response

Below is the response obtained on executing PHP script:

```
array(1) { ["error"]=> array(3) { ["code"]=> string(11) "BadArgument" 
    ["message"]=> string(26) "Invalid argument provided." ["details"]=> array(1)
    {[0]=> array(2) { ["code"]=> string(18) "RequestBodyInvalid" ["message"]=>
    string(68) "No request body provided or error in deserializing the request
    body." } } } }
```

PHP Script:

```
$url = 'URL';
$api_key = 'API';
$data = array(
    'Inputs'=> array(
        'My Experiment Name'=> array(
            "ColumnNames" => [['Column1'],
                              ['Column2'],
                              ['Column3'],
                              ['Column4'],
                              ['Column5'],
                              ['Column6'],
                              ['Column7']],
            "Values" => [ ['Value1'],
                          ['Value2'],
                          ['Value3'],
                          ['Value4'],
                          ['Value5'],
                          ['Value6'],
                          ['Value7']]
            ),
        ),
        'GlobalParameters' => new StdClass(),
    );

$body = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: Bearer '.$api_key, 'Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$response  = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
//echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump ($response);
```

I have followed few examples, still unable to crack it. Please let me know the solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error information, I think the issue was caused by requesting the ML REST API without correct json body.

I suggest that you can refer to the article ["Getting started with the Text Analytics APIs to detect sentiment, key phrases, topics and language"](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cognitive-services-text-analytics-quick-start) to correctly format your input rows in JSON as the request body and try again.

Hope it helps.

If you can update your question for specifying which ML REST API you used， I think it's very helpful for figuring out the issue.

Expect your update.